# Render number with nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, function, vuejs2, nuxt.js, v-model

### Need to do:

**I would like to make something like this:**

1
10
100
1 000
10 000
100 000
...

---

### Example (my code):

```
<div class="boxe-chiffre" v-if="pops.Population"><span>Population</span> {{pops.Population}}</div>
```

**{{pops.Population}}** is number and render like this : **96629€** and i would like **96 629€**

---

but i don't understand how to make that with nuxtjs 
(just format number)
Thanks !

Comment: Are you specifically looking for formatting as currency or just a way to separate the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specifically a nuxtJS problem, it's just a rudimentary JavaScript problem that can be solved using the `toLocaleString` method of numbers in JavaScript.

```
methods: {
  toCurrencyString(number){
    return number.toLocaleString('en-UK', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })
  }
}
```

The following method can be used to convert a number to its currency equivalent using just vanilla JavaScript.

You could try and split and splice spaces and the currency symbol into place for a multiple of different scenarios which might work for you in the short term, but it's not a lasting solution obviously. I started writing one out only to realize that it's a complete rabbit hole, you could also look at using a JS library such as accounting.js which might be more suitable.

Here's a js fiddle showing how to implement the component: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/177932/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my main problems is how to use javascript function on data

Comment: You should probably remove that answer as it isn't one, you'll need to add the toCurrencyString method to your methods object in your component. Afterwards you can call `{{toCurrencyString(pops.Population)}}`

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is inside [vue custom filters documents](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)
You can add filter only to your component or you can define it globaly (reusable)

Make js file inside plugins folders and add it inside your [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-plugins/) inside `nuxt.config.js` file. `import Vue from 'vue'` then use `Vue.filter()` function to define your custom filter

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.filter('currency', function (value) {
  // tanks @li-x for his simple formating function
  return value.toLocaleString('en-UK', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' })
  // you can add something like .replace(/,/g, ' ') after toLocaleString method to customize your formatted number
})
```

Then simply use it with `|` operator in [mustache](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text) like:

```
<div class="boxe-chiffre" v-if="pops.Population"><span>Population</span> {{pops.Population | currency}}</div>
```

Also you can pass some arguments to your filter function as desçibed in [documents](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)